# CSS failed to show for newly added <div>

Tags: jquery, html

i have a page which has the HTML code of:

```
 <div id="WF120412">
            <div id="F120412" class=editable>
                <h1 name=title>1. New Chapter</h1>
                <DIV name="note"></DIV>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="WF120413">
            <div id="F120413" class=editable>
                <h1 name=title>2. New Chapter</h1>
                <DIV name="note"></DIV>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The css code

```
.editable {
    cursor:default; padding: 1px;  position:relative;}
```

ok now when i click a button I would like to dynamically append a **NEW line** of code below to the above content without refreshing the page

```
 <div id="WF120414">
            <div id="F120414" class=editable>
                <h1 name=title>3. New Chapter</h1>
                <DIV name="note"></DIV>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The Code which i used to add is this

`$("#rightPaneContent").append(newChNote);` where newChNote is the new `<div>...</div>`

The latest added `3. New Chapter` got appear but the css style does not apply to it

Comment: what is `rightPaneContent`? this works: http://jsfiddle.net/dbhxH/

Comment: one assumes that the `#rightPaneContent` is the container that your div's live in?

Comment: if `#rightPaneContent` is container for your divs `id=WF120412, WF120413`, `newChNote` is a string which contains the third div and you js-code runs on `$(document).ready()` then your example should work. Or provide more information

Comment: Hi the new <div> is added but not the css .editable. The css did not apply to the new <DIV>

Comment: definitely smth strange, because it actually applies: http://jsfiddle.net/dbhxH/1/

Comment: Problem solved... whew .. my css code was overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this addresses your issue, http://jsfiddle.net/yq9TT/3/

Under the assumption that your rightPaneContent is the container, Use append and then innerHTML as illustrated in the example.

**EDIT** : Encompasses the Color issues as the user requested.

Comment: it seems user belinq failed to recognize the right answer igor answer seems perfect and ideal.

Comment: Ok Its no competition here mate, Igor can post his answer in the "Answers" section and get his points if need be.Both our answers are right and this is a forum for helping people out.

Comment: Hi the new <div> is shown but not the css .editable. The css did not apply to the new <DIV>. I tried added color:red to the .editable CSS but the new <Div> did not get shown

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the chapter id. I think this id should be increased if you add more chapter.

Please find the solution http://jsfiddle.net/FMPgU/1/. In this solution dynamic id is considered. If you check div id using firebug you will find that. I add a little trick here. I have added a class for the chapter.

The markup is as follows. notice class="chapter". This is crucial. I did the trick here

```
        <div id="rightPaneContent">
            <div id="WF120412" class="chapter">
                        <div id="F120412" class=editable>
                            <h1 name=title>1. New Chapter</h1>
                            <DIV name="note"></DIV>
                        </div>
            </div>

            <div id="WF120413" class="chapter">
                <div id="F120413" class=editable>
                    <h1 name=title>2. New Chapter</h1>
                    <DIV name="note"></DIV>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <input type="button" id="btnAddChapter" value="Add Chapter" />
```

The script is here

```
            $('#btnAddChapter').click(function() {
              var lastId = $("#rightPaneContent div.chapter:last").attr("id").split("WF")[1];
             var count = $("#rightPaneContent div.chapter").size();
             count++;
             var newId = parseInt(lastId,10)+1;
             var newChapter = "<div id='WF"+newId+"' class='chapter'>"+
                "<div id='F"+newId+"' class='editable'>"+
                        "<h1 name=title>"+count+". New Chapter</h1>"+
                        "<DIV name='note'></DIV>"+
                 "</div>"+
             "</div>";
             $("#rightPaneContent").append(newChapter);
            });
```